# Why does convert add half an empty page

Tags: pdf, convert

Try running the following:

```
pdftk a-i0778e.pdf cat 1 output page.pdf
convert page.pdf page.jpeg (or png, whatever you want)
```

returns a weird png file with left half blank and the image of the pdf on the right half.. any ideas why?

if you do convert on that full pdf btw, first page is still like that, and last page is the inverse (image on left half, empty right half).. oddness..